# Webpack generates wrong url for images that were included using file-loader

Tags: image, webpack, vue.js

I am using webpack `file-loader` to include images in my build. Webpack compiles fine and copies images from `dev/assets` to `dist/images`

BUT the  tag in the generated HTML is wrong:

```
<img src="/dist/images/triangle.svg">
```

It should be:

```
<img src="./images/triangle.svg">
```

Is my webpack config wrong for file-loader?

**.vue file:**

```
<div>
     <img src='./images/thing.png'>
</div>

.style {
   background: url('./images/anotherthing.png');
}
```

**Webpack config (simplified)**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'images/'
        }
      }
    ]
   }
```

**webpack config (complete)**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    publicPath: './',
    filename: 'js/build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath:'./images/'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(json)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: './data/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to set `publicPath: '/'`.

Think of `publicPath` as the directory of your assets relative to the root of the public facing domain. If your server is serving files from `/dist` to `example.com`, that would mean that assets in `/dist/images` are publicly accessible at `example.com/images` (`file-loader` already adds the `/images` bit as you've witnessed).

Comment: Thanks that was it. Only problem now is that `webpack-dev-server` can no longer find my project. I think that's why I added `dist` to `publicPath`.

Comment: You can change the `webpack-dev-server` config using the `devServer` property. See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/

Comment: Cool, that works! Last problem now is that the server does not auto-compile and hot-reload after the code changes. It does compile when I use `webpack --watch` and manually refresh the html page.

Comment: Can you share the remainder of your Webpack config?

Comment: I added the complete config file.